# How to return unescaped response in Snap web application

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I want to return some preformatted html in a snap application. However, when the handler below is served,

```
aPage :: Handler App App ()
aPage = do 
  writeText "<p>This is a page</p>"
```

The output is couched in < pre > tags.

```
...<body><pre><p>This is a page</p></pre></body> ...
```

Is there a simple way to add a verbatim string to the response body?

Comment: Snap is doing exactly what you asked. Consider setting the content type appropriately and sending a full HTML document. If you do both of those, your browser is more likely to do what you expect. However you're inspecting the browser state, it's telling you how it renders plaintext documents as DOM nodes

Comment: Thanks. I was way off. That did it.

Comment: Yikes. After re-reading my comment, it sounds way more curt than I meant. Sorry about that, and I'm glad you sorted things out.

Comment: Thanks for that, I did have to take a deep breath and read through a few times. In the end, it sorted me right out. So thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

As Carl pointed out in the comment to my question, it was not "escaped" to begin with. What I was seeing was the browsers rendition of the plaintext document. Simply sending a properly formatted document gives me what I was expecting.

```
aPage :: Handler App App ()
aPage = do 
  writeText "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><p>This is a page</p></body></html>"
```

After fiddling with Blaze-html and Lucid, two libraries for generating html, I was sure some sort of formatting was going on under the hood and thought some sort of `toHtmlRaw` function was needed. Not at all the answer I was expecting.